# How opened file cannot be rewind by seek(0) after using with open() in python

Tags: python, file, seek

While I was trying to print file content line by line in python, I cann't rewind the opened file by **f.seek(0)** to print the content if the file was opened by **with open("file_name") as f:**
but, I can do this if I use **open("file_name") as f:** 
then **f.seek(0)**

Following is my code

```
with open("130.txt", "r") as f:             #f is a FILE object
    print (f.read())                        #so f has method: read(), and f.read() will contain the newline each time 

f.seek(0)                             #This will Error!
with open("130.txt", "r") as f:       #Have to open it again, and I'm aware the indentation should change  
for line in f:                    
    print (line, end="")          

f = open("130.txt", "r")
f.seek(0)
for line in f:
    print(line, end="")

f.seek(0)                           #This time OK!
for line in f:
    print(line, end="")
```

I am a python beginner, can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `with` is to clean up the resource when the block ends, which in this case would include closing the file handle.

You should be able to `.seek` within the `with` block like this, though:

```
with open('130.txt','r') as f:
  print (f.read())

  f.seek(0)
  for line in f:
    print (line,end='')
```

From your comment, `with` in this case is syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
f = open(...)
try:
  # use f
finally:
  f.close()

# f is still in scope, but the file handle it references has been closed
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the first FILE object **f** disappear or not? 
With *type(f)* I got: *<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>*
which seems it still exists. Hard time for me switching to python.

Comment: `f` still exists and will reference the wrapper around the file handle, but the handle it actually wraps will have been closed, so when subsequent calls are made they will fail. I certainly wish `f` would be scoped to the `with` block, but Python is rather loose with that sort of thing.

Comment: I see, the handler is still the there, but the content it wrapped has been closed. Problem cleared!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

The first `f.seek(0)` will throw an error because

```
with open("130.txt", "r") as f:
    print (f.read())
```

will close the file at the end of the block (once the file has be printed out)

You'll need to do something like:

```
with open("130.txt", "r") as f:
    print (f.read())

    # in with block
    f.seek(0)
```